# Access async object param into child component in Angular 4

Tags: angular

i have one problem about angular access async object param.

firstly,this code is worked:

```js
param$:Observable<string>();
```

```html
<child [name]="param$ | async"></child>
```

but when param$ 's type is object like this

```js
param$:Observalbe<object>();
```

i can not use this way to access object's value

```html
<child [name]="param$.name | async"></child>
```

the child component's param name is a async value:

```js
export class Parent{
    private parentname;
    constuctor(http:HttpClient){
      http.get(...)
          .subscribe(obj => {
             this.parentname = obj.name;
             //  parentname can get successfully
      });
    }
}

export class Child{
  @Input() name:string;
}
```

```html
<child [name]="parentname"></child>
```

by this way, the child component's param name is `undefined`.

then i  changed some code in  child component and it worked:

```js
private _name:string;
@Input() set name(value:string){
   this._name = value
}
```

when parent component assess async parem to child component , and this param is not a stream , how to resolve it .
does anyone has better way to rolve this problem? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read an observable or asynchronous task using the `async` pipe with **operator precedence** where `bracket` is processed first, and also making use of the `?` operator to make sure our object don't return `undefined` and it breaks our flow, which means if there's an object read the `name` field else leave it and move on, the code below should help you figure it out better.

```js
    export class App {
      name:string;
      asyncObject:{name:string};
      asyncObject2:Observable<{name:string}>;
      constructor() {
        this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`;
        this.asynchronous().subscribe((data)=>{
          this.asyncObject = data;
        });
        
        this.asyncObject2 =  this.asynchronous();
      }
      
      asynchronous():Observable<{name:string}>{
        return Observable.create(observer => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          observer.next({name:'First Theo'});
          console.log("am done");
          observer.complete(); //to show we are done with our processing 
        }, 2000);
      });
      }
    }
```

here is the template file

```html
    <div>
          <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
          Loading this async
          <b> name: {{asyncObject?.name}}</b>
          <br>
          Loading for second async that's an observable
           <b> name2: {{(asyncObject2 | async)?.name}}</b>
          
        </div>
```

Observe this line  `<b> name2: {{(asyncObject2 | async)?.name}}</b>` the way i used the braces to make sure the async pipe is processed first.

Here is a working [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/pSGEL4?p=preview) demo

Answer (score 1):

Try like this :

```
export class Parent {
    private parentname: string;
    constructor(private http: Http) {
        this.http.get(...)
            .map(response => response.json())
            .subscribe(result => {
                this.parentname = result.name;
            });
    }
}

<child [name]="parentname"></child>

export class Child {
    @Input name: string;
}
```

Comment: hi the parentname param can get successfully, i mean the when page first render, the child param name is undefiled because parent 's parentname is undefined , the by the http method , the parentname 's value is changed.  i can use ngOnChanges() hook ,see that the child name first is undefined, then, it change to the http's get value